# Spivak proof partition of unity: case 2 (countable compact sets)

Tags: compactness

I have a question about Spivak's proof on the partition of unity (see below).
[image]
Spivak first proves the case where $A$ is compact. Then he proceeds with case 2:
[image]
I don't really understand what this $U$ here is. Is $U$ simply an open subset of $\mathcal O$? And we consider all open subsets $U$ then? If so, what do we need this $U$? Why can't we just take
$$
\mathcal O\cap(\operatorname{interior}A_{i+1}-A_{i-2}),
$$
where $\mathcal O$ is an open cover of $A$.

Comment: $U$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, whereas $\mathcal O$ is a set of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. So the intersection you wrote isn't defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal O$ is an open cover, so by definition it is a family of open sets. That is
$$\mathcal O = \lbrace U_\beta\rbrace_{\beta\in B},$$
where $B$ is just some set and $U_\beta$ are open.
Then for each $i$ he creates a new family
$$\mathcal O_i= \lbrace U_\beta \cap(\operatorname{interior}A_{i+1}-A_{i-2}) \rbrace _{\beta\in B}$$
and claims that this new family $\mathcal O_i$ is an open cover (but for other set).